# How can I remove a one to many relationship on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify

I have a 1-n relationship between the `Team` model and the `League` model on my AWS Amplify Datastore that I'm using on a React Native application.

When I want to create a connection between a `Team` and a `League`, I update the (*optional*) leagueID field of the team:

```
const updatedTeam = await DataStore.save(
  Team.copyOf(team, (updated) => {
    updated.leagueID = league.id;
  })
);
```

But when I want to remove a `Team` from its `League`, I didn't find the right way to achieve it.

Setting the `leagueId` to `undefined` doesn't work:

```
const updatedTeam = await DataStore.save(
  Team.copyOf(team, (updated) => {
    updated.leagueID = undefined;
  })
);
```

I've also tried to delete the actual property, but it doesn't work neither:

```
const updatedTeam = await DataStore.save(
  Team.copyOf(team, (updated) => {
    delete updated.leagueID
  })
);
```

Searching on the [official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmtsz.png), I didn't find any reference about this case.

I'm also wondering if there's any cache enabled on aws that doesn't allow me to see the updated data.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]